# Mysqli / Ajax How to load x more Results each request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Here I have a database request:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT * FROM posts p INNER JOIN friends f ON
      ((p.from_user=f.user1 OR p.from_user=f.user2) AND (f.user1='$ownid' OR f.user2='$ownid') AND f.accepted='1') 
      GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.uhrzeit DESC ;           
");
```

And a simple Javascript for checking the scroll position.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1500) {

    } 
});
```

Sure, these are only Code Snippets without the Document Ready Function and such.

My question is now: How can I get the first 15 results on page load and then the next 15 results with an Ajax request every time when the scroll function is triggered?

And how can I implement this into my actual query?

Thanks for every Answer. 
If there missing Informations please request and i will update.

EDIT 
What i did now

JS

```
var offset = 15,
scrollEnd = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.footer').offset().top && typeof scrollEnd !== 'undefined' && !scrollEnd){
                alert();
                $.ajax({
                url: "./ajax/loadmore_homeposts.php",
                data : {offset: offset},
                beforeSend: function(){
            scrollEnd = true;
            }
                success:function(r){
                        if(r.data.length){
                            // + you have result
                            offset *=2;
                            // prepare the html and append into the respective container

                            alert(r);

                            scrollEnd = false;
                        }else{
                        alert("<p>No more result</p>");
                            $('.result_container').append('<p>No more result</p>');
                        }
            }
            })
            }
             });
```

PHP

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


    $ownid= $_SESSION['SESSION'];
    $offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ?  $_GET['offset'] : 0;
    $limit = 15;

   $query=mysqli_query($db,
            "
            SELECT * FROM posts p INNER JOIN friends f ON
             ((p.from_user=f.user1 OR p.from_user=f.user2) AND (f.user1='$ownid' OR f.user2='$ownid') AND f.accepted='1') 
                 GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.uhrzeit DESC  limit $offset,$limit;           
             ");


    $data = [];
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode( ['data'=>$data]);

    ?>
```

Comment: At first your scroll check is not correct. You should not check the scrollTop with a constant , you should detect the offset top of your footer and then determine that your scroll offset is larger or close to the footer offset, So it means that user has scroll down to the footer, so you have to load new content

Comment: Can you give me a Example about it? Would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql offset and limit for this. Like this

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menuitem LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page;

It will peek up offset number row and no of items in $items_per_page.

Answer (score 0):

```
            // + in php
            $offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ?  $_GET['offset'] : 0;
            $limit = 15;
            $result = mysqli_query("[YOur query] limit $offset,$limit");

            $data = [];
            while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode( ['data'=>$data]);

            //=  in javascript
            var offset = 15,scrollEnd = false;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.footer').offset().top && typeof scrollEnd !== 'undefined' && !scrollEnd){
                $.ajax({
                url: your url
                data : {offset: offset},
                beforeSend: function(){
            scrollEnd = true;
            }
                success:function(r){
                        if(r.data.length){
                            // + you have result
                            offset *=2;
                            // prepare the html and append into the respective container
                            scrollEnd = false;
                        }else{
                            $('.result_container').append('<p>No more result</p>');
                        }
            }
            })
            }
            })
```

Comment: Okey thanks :) i tried it out and i updated my Question with what i did so far. But there is a Error anywhere? Dont seems to work atm :/

Comment: And i have not a footer div :D ?  i did one but it doesnt trigger

Comment: You are not getting the first alert inside the scroll callback? if not try `$(window).scrollTop()` this code on browser console and note the value and `$('.footer').offset().top` in same manner. Once the first one is greater than the second one the scroll callback should fire

Comment: Thanks i will test it later :)